# Template localization on background

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, background-task

I'm using Django-background-tasks to sending emails asynchronously. When I'm sending email in view, localization work perfect, but when I'm trying to send same email from background, Django rendering template with default locale. Here is code which I'm using to sending emails :

Function that I'm calling from views.py

**tasks.py**

```
@background()
def send_email_async(email, json):
    send_email_support_request(email, json)
```

**email_utils.py**

```
def send_email_support_request(email, json_data):
    c = {
        'request_id': json_data['request_id']
    }
    template = 'email_support_request.html'
    email_header = {
        'message': "All Data request",
        'subject': "Support request"
    }
    send_email(c, template, email_header, email)
    return

def send_email(context_dict, email_template_name, email_header_data, user_email):
    subject = ''.join(email_header_data['subject'].splitlines())
    email_render = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context_dict)
    email = EmailMessage(subject=subject,
                         body=email_render,
                         from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                         to=[user_email])
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.send()
    return
```

**Template file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load i18n %}

<html lang="en" style="background-color: rgb(238,243,246)">

...

<span class="line-text" style="margin-bottom: 20px; display: inline-block;">
{% trans "Thank you for your request!"%}
</span>
```

How to make Django-rest-framework render template according to the language specified in header Accept-Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's best solution, but I'm reading locale from request in view, and than passing locale to functions and finally rendering template :

```
with translation.override(locale):
    email_render = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context_dict)
```